# Help deploying SFDX metadata to a Patch Org?

Tags: salesforcedx, patchorg

I'm using SFDX for development, and I've got a managed package in my packaging org. I need to tweak some things and don't want to increment the version... but I don't know how to deploy to a Patch Org. Can't find any docs on it...

Any guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your sfdx project into metadata format and then deploy to the patch org. Do something like,

`sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi`

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi -u <patch org username> -w 1000
```

Comment: quick follow up. If I have a second patch after I've completed the first, do I use the same patch org, or do I have to create a second patch org?

Comment: If you are doing any changes to the same major release, you can use the same patch org. Deploy changes and upload another version.

Comment: You could use the new [sfdx force:source:deploy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/269573/55891) to deploy