# How to push code to production with Visual Studio Code & DX

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to develop new functionality.

However, after completing the testing in the sandbox, I want to push the code to production. When I choose "SFDX: Deploy Code to org", it fails with errors -

```
INVALID_OPERATION: rollbackOnError option must be true on a production org
```

and

```
INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations
```

The code is in the new "source format", but I'm not developing in scratch orgs (I started the project with "SFDX: Create Project with Manifest").

Question 1: Do I need to convert the source to Metadata API format before I can deploy to production? This is not how the instructions in release notes are written:

> To deploy source to an org without source tracking (to an org that’s
>   not a scratch org), right-click a manifest, a source file, or a
>   directory in the Visual Studio Code explorer. Select SFDX: Deploy
>   Source to Org.
>
> https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_vscode_any_org.htm

However, the Salesforce DX Developer Guide seems to imply it:

> Release Your App to Production
>
> **After you convert from source format to metadata format**, and package metadata from one org, you can release your app in a different org.
>
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_mdapi_production.htm

Question 2: If I don't need to convert the source format and can push to production directly, how do I set up Visual Studio Code / CLI to avoid the two errors?

Comment: ...As a programmer, hearing that you push something to production directly from your IDE fills me with sadness. https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-f5-key-is-not-a-build-process/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have two choices. First, you can use force:package commands to create an unlocked package. You can install this in production with force:package:install; it is similar to installing an AppExchange package. Otherwise, you would need to use force:source:convert to get a mdapi style format, then use force:mdapi:deploy with the relevant test level (e.g. RunLocalTests) and set rollbackOnError to true. Check out the [Salesforce CLI Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm) for specific details, or `sfdx help force:<command>` for command-level help direct from the console. I do not believe that you're currently allowed to create unlocked packages directly via the GUI, but you can open a terminal by using the Terminal > Create New Terminal option, which will open a sfdx environment by default.

Comment: Thank you for making the 2 options explicit. I think my disconnect was that I was expecting the entire development workflow to go through VS Code menus.

Comment: @t0tl I expect it will *some day*, but today isn't that day. Right now, it's focused more on development, but there's a few places that are either unclear or not implemented yet.

Comment: Why does Trailhead make it seem like this is possible with LWCs, see section: [Deploy Files To Production Org](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/push-lightning-web-component-files#Tdxn4tBK-heading9)?

Comment: @Xtremefaith At the time this answer was written, LWC wasn't even announced yet. LWC deployments presumably don't run tests, because there are no server-side tests to run (LWC is basically just HTML+JavaScript). However, if you also need to deploy Apex Code, I believe you'd have to still go through the above process. I don't have a way to double-check right now, but this answer may be outdated. If you have a production org you want to try it on, be my guest.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sorry, I wasn't knocking your answer, I was hoping you had some insight because the trailhead is misleading. Just realized the trailhead is referring to a [beta command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_deploy) that is failing cause there is no way I see to set `rollbackOnError` to true for production. To confirm, converting and then using `mdapi:deploy` works without test for LWCs

Comment: @Xtremefaith Thanks for the confirmation. I think they'll get around to it some day, but for now, the recommended path would be unlocked packages if you can afford to use them.

Comment: As of v46.0, you can now deploy to production with `force:source:deploy`

Answer (score 20):

As of Summer '19 (v46.0), the `INVALID_OPERATION` errors you were hitting are no longer an issue!

**`force:source:deploy` now works when [deploying to production](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm).**  See an example below:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass:MyApexClass -l RunSpecifiedTests -r MyApexClass_Test -w 3 -u MyProductionOrg
```

Comment: That is unbelievable!

Comment: wish it can be done by VS code but not outside of it someday...

Comment: How do you do this but just 1 LWC bundle? I normally just do this on VScode via right click the lwc i want to deploy then click "SFDX: Deploy Source to org".

Comment: @compski `sfdx force:source:deploy -m LightningComponentBundle:myLwcComp -u MyDestinationOrg`  You can see a list of all the different Metadata types [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm)

Comment: It doesn't work for me in version 48.

Comment: @picardo You have to make sure you have a connected org to deploy to and all the files in your local project.  If you're having specific issues, I suggest creating a new question altogether and the community can help you from there.  I use these commands daily with v48 and it's working for me

Answer (score 3):

The "SFDX: Deploy Code to org" command uses the `sfdx force:source:deploy` command, which according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm) only deploys to non-production orgs (at least as of Spring '19).

**A nifty way to deploy to production** with these new commands (as inspired by the documentation above) is as follows:

1. Set the `SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR` environment variable to a place that's easily accessible (like the `metadata` folder within your current project):

```
SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=/path/to/mydxproject/metadata
```

2. Retrieve *the exact metadata* you want to deploy to production, like as follows:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass:MyUtilClass,ApexClass:MyUtilClass_Test -u MySandboxOrg
```

3. This will create a folder within your `metadata` folder with the metadata .zip file or package.xml file that you're looking for.  Deploy from the zip file as follows (and feel free to add any other helpful options as specified in the [mdapi Commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm)):

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f ./metadata/sdx_sourceRetrieve_1554058974901/unpackaged.zip -u MyProductionOrg -w 3
```

4. If the deployment takes longer than three minutes (as specified in the above `-w 3` flag), then check your deployment status in the production org itself or via:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy:report -u MyProductionOrg
```

This allows you to use the new `force:source:retrieve` command and have it auto-convert into metadata, without having to call `force:source:convert` manually