# sf:INVALID_OPERATION: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, production, vs-code

While deploying code in vsCode from sandbox to production I get the below error

> sf:INVALID_OPERATION: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot
>   be used in production organizations

As per the error, I need to change the value of testLevel but I am not able to find where and how can I change it to RunLocalTests

Could someone please help me to change the value of testLevel in vsCode

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE 9/2019**

As of Summer '19 v46.0, `force:source:deploy` now works when deploying to production, and you'll no longer get that testLevel error message.

You can set the test level using the `-l` flag and use `-u` to point to your connected Production org:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass:MyClass -l RunLocalTests -u MyProductionOrg
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

If you're using `force:source:deploy`, it doesn't work when deploying to production, which is why those `testLevel` errors are showing up.  As of Spring 19, you can't adjust those parameters (and this is by design as far as I can tell).  This limitation can be found on the `force:source:deploy` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm):

> The force:source:deploy, force:source:retrieve, and force:source:delete commands work on sandboxes, Developer Edition orgs, and trial orgs, but not production orgs. For production orgs, *continue to use force:mdapi:deploy and force:mdapi:retrieve*.

For a nice trick to deploy from Sandbox to Production, see my answer to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244951/how-to-push-code-to-production-with-visual-studio-code-dx) - I use this on a daily basis now

Comment: thank you, Brian, but Instead of using the command line is there any other way to deploy code from the vs code just like we deploy code to sandBox?

Comment: I don't think the Salesforce extensions for VS code are there yet - although I think on the roadmap they are proposing a UI interface to select items to deploy to Production (like you would use in MavensMate)

Comment: Thank you for your help Brian

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you, do you think there is a way we can adjust this command per Project, so that we can do typical save and it builds/deploys automatically?

Comment: It already exists for deploying to non-production orders - in VS Code, go into Settings (Cmd+,), click on the Workspace subtab, search for Salesforce, and you'll see a Push or Deploy on Save setting.  Set that to true and you're set.  JSON looks like: `"salesforcedx-vscode-core.push-or-deploy-on-save.enabled": true`.  Deploying on Save to Production is a bad practice at best and don't think this setting will help you there, nor should it :-)

Comment: OK Thanks so the answer is No, we cannot automate Deploy to Prod on save without scripting it.
There are always use cases:)
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To deploy to production using the CLI:

Deploy a Class with specific Test Class (ApexClass:MyCless = metadatatype:fileName)

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass:MyCless -l RunSpecifiedTests -r TestClass -u ConnectedOrg
```

Deploy Classes with specific Test Classes (comma Separated metadatatype:fileName,metadatatype:fileName)

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass:MyCless,ApexClass:TestCless,ApexClass:OtherTestClass -l RunSpecifiedTests -r TestClass,OtherTestClass -u ConnectedOrg
```