# How do I see limits associated to REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: TotalRequests Limit exceeded

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, governorlimits

After using `sfdx force:source:deploy` a good amount today to deploy to production (see how to [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/269573/55891)), I hit the following error:

> ERROR running force:source:deploy:  REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: TotalRequests Limit exceeded.

What limits is this referring to, and how can I see how many I've consumed so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sfdx force:limits:api:display`

Comment: Nice, thank you!  The limit that was exceeded for me there was `DailyApiRequests`

Answer (score 1):

After a quick check to Setup -> Environments -> System Overview, I see that the API usage has been exceeded (which was very unexpected and not caused by my development efforts):
[image]

I guess the lesson here is that `force:source:deploy` consumes API calls