# VS Code Deploying User Interface similar to MavensMate?

Tags: deployment, mavensmate, vs-code, deployment-api

One of the things I loved about MavensMate was how easy it was to deploy Metadata from one SFDC Org to another. See image below - it allowed you to select which metadata types you wanted to deploy and handled numerous SFDC Connection credentials beautifully.

[image]

We have since switched to VS Code and I haven't seen a UI that allows us to quickly deploy multiple metadata types like we used to. I see there is a very similar StackExchange question posted here: [How to push code to production with Visual Studio Code & DX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244951/how-to-push-code-to-production-with-visual-studio-code-dx)

However it looks doesn't provide a nice UI like MavensMate/Sublime used to. Am I missing something or is this just not as slick?

Comment: I haven't used mavensmate, but I can say that no two products are similar. You may see similar features but in general you will see differences too. As far as I have used VS Code, I haven't seen an option where you can pick and choose components to be deployed. But it does provide you a quick way to say right click on the component itself and then deploy it to the org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a feature in the core bundle, nor does there need to be. VS Code handles multiple orgs without any problems, it's just different. You don't need to select individual files, because you can have as many folders as you need to organize your metadata. You no longer have a single `src/classes` folder, you can instead have `core/classes`, `marketing/classes`, and `test/classes` (or however you decide to organize your code structure). Once organized, you can easily deploy a single subset by right-clicking and deploying a folder. You can also deploy individual files if you'd like, but I find this to be less useful in daily tasks. That said, VS Code has a pretty robust extension system. It'd be possible for an enthusiast to build their own UI and even share it with others in the VS Code Extension Marketplace. If there's enough demand, it likely will be built by someone at some point. See also questions on here like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/204998) for more information on folder structures in SFDX/VS Code.

Comment: Oh... so I could theoretically I create a folder for a specific project and deploy the entire folder to Production?

Comment: @rmarq423 Certainly. For example, we've started migrating to DX ourselves, and we already have four "projects" that we've organized into Unlocked Packages. This allows us to deploy specific sets of functionality without deploying all the metadata or calculating deltas. It's been pretty enlightening so far, and we're definitely looking forward to doing more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Something that is related, but not exactly the same as how MavensMate allowed you to deploy Metadata is the VSCode [Org Browser](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/org-browser/).

[image]

> 1. Open Org Browser
> 2. Refresh available metadata types in the org
> 3. Default org
> 4. Metadata type
> 5. Metadata component
> 6. Refresh components for metadata type
> 7. Retrieve source for metadata component

It is currently in Beta and only supports retrieving metadata from non-scratch orgs.

You would still need a separate mechanism to deploy source metadata to another org.

You could raise a [feature request](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20label%3Aarea%3Aorgbrowser%20) to allow it to deploy selected metadata.

---

UPDATE: [See Package.xml Utilities](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1710)

> **Deploy Working Set** - Deploys all the items in this working set to the currently selected org.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all of the above, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator gives you a simple GUI for adding items to your `manifest/package.xml`.